# convert text into bitmap or movieclip with transparent background

Tags: actionscript-3

how to convert text into a bitmap or a mocieclip with transparent background.
i could convert the text into bitmap but it has got a white background..

Comment: How you are converting text to bitmap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to make sure the BitmapData object is initialized with a transparent background-fill-color (the 4th parameter to the constructor). This should work (assuming you have your text in a TextField):

```
var snapshot:BitmapData = new BitmapData(textField.width, textField.height, true, 0x00000000);
snapshot.draw(textField, new Matrix());
```

See also the [as3 docs for the BitmapData constructor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#BitmapData())

Comment: that looks like it could useful, but after this step, what would i do to display it on the screen?
thanks in advance--

Comment: You'd add it via a Bitmap object to the display list: `var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap (bd);
addChild(bmp);`

Comment: What is the "new Matrix()" for? The AS3 documentation says that you can just leave it at null (or no parameter at all) and it will be the same as using "new Matrix()". https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()